# make div occupy available height and display scrollbar in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a page, with a title, some controls, 3 tables displaying data and a footer. I want the header, the controls, footer and the 2 tables to be displayed at all times. The 3rd table I want it to expand to occupy the available height in the client window, and display a scroll bar in the containing div (The data in that table has a lot of rows and will always need a scroll bar).

I managed to find [a solution](https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/css/how-to-make-a-div-take-the-remaining-height) (solution 2 in the article) that works exactly as as I need in Google Chrome and Opera using `display: table;` and `display:table-row`. The problem in other browsers (Firefox, Edge, IE11), the div containing the table would stretch and not be scrollable and the footer would be hidden.

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nts59oL/5/) to demonstrate my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/3nts59oL/5/
The code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {} .fill {
  height: 100%;
}
.panel {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.panel > div {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
}
.panel > div.fillavailable {
  height: auto;
}
.controls {
  background-color: red;
}
hr {
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2px;
}
.content {
  background-color: green;
}
.contentContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
.maincontent {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="panel fill">
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fillavailable">
      <div class="container panel fill">
        <div class="controls">
          Some buttons and links here.
        </div>
        <div class="content fillavailable">
          <div class="panel fill">
            <div>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>Some data(typically 2-3 rows)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Some data(typically 2-3 rows)</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>More data(typically 1-3 rows)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>More data(typically 1-3 rows)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>More data(typically 1-3 rows)</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="fillavailable">

              <div class="maincontent fill">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>lots of data</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <footer>footer text</footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The green tables are the fixed ones, and the orange table need to expand as needed to fill the available screen height. How can I fix this code to work in IE10+, Firefox? I don't care much about IE9 or earlier. I have a separate mobile version of the page, but a solution that works fine on mobile is welcome.

Also please note that I don't know the height of any the elements at design time, this is why I didn't go for a solution using `position: absolute` or css calc.

Comment: I edited my original question to include the code in the post itself rather than just a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one here: https://jsfiddle.net/7xrbqmba/

Look at the CSS, you can just play with `position:` and that's all.

It's safer than in the link you provided, because if the length/size of the content is bigger than the container, it's still working.

Next time try to show some code - it's easier then to determinate the problem.

Comment: I did show code. There is a link to a jsfiddle in my post. Is there a way for your solution to work with 100% width and height instead of fixed 300px and 400px? Or do I have to resort to javascript and handle window resize events?

Comment: I edited my original question to include the code in the post itself rather than just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: should work without any problem with any sizes :) and what I meant by this "code showing" :D Just specify some code from the file where you think the problem is and put it here, it's then easy to find the solution quicker ;)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but using bootstrap would greatly simplify your problem and more problems like this in the future. You can fix column and row sizes according to the device that the user is using as they have a very nice grid system.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid